# What is Markovnikov's addition?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology

The electrophilic addition of $\ce{HBr}$ across an unsymmetrical alkene follows Markovnikov's addition, but sometimes if the addition occurs via rearrangement then should we call it a Markovnikov addition?

Earlier, in an entrance exam, a similar question was asked and they have given the correct answer which states Markovnikov's addition for a reaction that occurs without a rearrangement.

In my opinion, if addition occurs without rearrangement then it should be Markovnikov's addition.

Comment: I always remembered Markovnikov addition as "the rich get richer" (in terms of protons). i.e. the carbon with more hydrogens will receive another, while the corresponding carbon will receive the halogen etc. As far as your question goes, I think it fair to say that mechanism is irrelevant. It's just a description based on observed products.

Comment: There is a difference between Markovnikov's addition and Markovnikov's addition product. The former always holds true as the carbocation formed initially due to an electrometric shift of electrons always happens at the most substituted carbon. However, Markovnikov's product does not account for rearrangements. If the carbocation rearranges to form a more stable carbocation, the product obtained usually won't be called a Markovnikov's product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of Markivnikov or anti-Markovnikov addition fundamentally isn't related to the mechanism by which a reaction took place, rather, the term is a way of describing the observed products obtained from certain kinds of addition.

The original statement of  Markovnikov addition is as follows, and applies *specifically* to the addition of hydrogen halides ($\ce{HX}$) across an alkene:

> In the addition of hydrogen halides to unsymmetrically constituted [unsaturated] hydrocarbons, the halogen atom becomes attached to the carbon bearing the lesser number of hydrogen atoms.

The statement was a purely empirical one (i.e. it was based on the *results* of experiment, rather than any consideration of the mechanism/pathway that the reaction had taken). It can also be expanded to consider any addition of a polar reagent ($\ce{RX}$) across alkenes and alkenes. The following definition is taken from the IUPAC Gold Book (a standard reference for definition of chemical terminology):

> In the heterolytic addition of a polar molecule to an alkene or alkyne, the more electronegative (nucleophilic) atom (or part) of the polar molecule becomes attached to the carbon atom bearing the smaller number of hydrogen atoms.

Thinking about the situation mechanistically, the Markovnikov rule basically just says that the less electronegative atom in the polar reagent $\ce{RX}$ ends up bound to the end of the alkene (or alkyne) most able to stabilise a developing positive charge (i.e. the most hindered end of the alkene/alkyne).

In terms of labelling the products of reactions, as discussed in your question, its perfectly valid to describe the products as those of Markovnikov addition (as stated previously, the term itself is saying nothing directly about mechanism, even if implied).

Comment: Good point, but it may still be useful to point out that in practice, Markovnikov additions usually proceed by carbocation or halonium Intermediates, whereas the two commonly taught anti-Markovnikov additions proceed by radical and concerted pathways (rather than cationic).

Comment: I think my *point* was that its not really saying anything about mechanism at all.  Being able to class reactions as Markovnikov vs anti-Markovnikov is simply a convenient correlation. I'd possibly go further and  actively advise for **not** putting reactions into boxes like that.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia tells me:

> The rule states that with the addition of a protic acid HX to an
>   asymmetric alkene, the acid hydrogen (H) becomes attached to the
>   carbon with fewer alkyl substituents, and the halide (X) group becomes
>   attached to the carbon with more alkyl substituents. Alternatively,
>   the rule can be stated that the hydrogen atom is added to the carbon
>   with the greatest number of hydrogen atoms while the X component is
>   added to the carbon with the least number of hydrogen atoms.

So, even with rearrangements, the halogen would still attack the most substituted site, so I'd say **yes**, you can consider it a Markovkinov addition.

Comment: If I take 3-phenyl propene then bromine goes to benzylic carbon which is having more number of hydrogen initially

Comment: @ArvindTiwari This might be a flaw in Markonikoff's rule. Nonetheless, don't use Markonikoff's rule. Simply compare carbocation stability.